# Child pages disabled in IE

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I have a site set up with the Wordpress Twenty Ten theme. I edited the CSS in order to make the nav bar elements stretch across the nav, instead of piling up on the left side. Now, however, the top level pages can be clicked on, put the child pages are disabled and disappear upon scrolling over them in IE. Beyond bizarre. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the site: http://www.econforensics.com

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/svx8hNeK

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: it seems to work fine even in IE7.. I don't know what you are seeing..can u post a screen shot.

Comment: Strange. Can't get Jing working on my other machine, a video would be much more helpful, but here is essentially what is happening: http://screencast.com/t/dcHbRFYa

Comment: hey take a look this http://jsbin.com/ujeje4 this is what i am seeing..let me know.

Comment: Very weird, it looks like it is working fine for you. In IE8, when you move down as you did in the screencast, the drop down vanishes.

Comment: Although I don't love the idea you could always try to force IE7 compatiblilty mode by adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />` to your `<head>` See: http://brurls.com/5at2e.

Comment: That is a terrible, terrible suggestion BrandonRandon. Terrible...

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to fix this problem in IE7:
[image]

In `style.css`, at approximately line 407, change this:

```
#access .menu-header li,
div.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;

}
```

to this (*there was already an empty line for me!*):

```
#access .menu-header li,
div.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1
}
```

It fixes the issue, which was caused by a *bug* in IE7.